# How to make Kendo-UI Editor readonly inside a ng-repeat loop based on database data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have to form repeated kendo editors based on database list which can be either editable or readonly.I was able to implement the repeated Editors but was unable to make it readonly based on certain database field. This readonly has to be done on the page load event.

I am doing this using angularjs.

```
 <fieldset data-ng-repeat="source in sourceData">
                 <textarea kendo-editor="editorwidget" ng-model="source.Text" id="{{source.id}}" k-tools='[
                        "bold", "italic", "underline", "createTable",      "addColumnLeft", "addColumnRight",
                        "addRowAbove",
                        "addRowBelow", "deleteRow", "deleteColumn", "justifyLeft",
                        "justifyCenter",
                        "justifyRight",
                        "justifyFull",
                        "insertUnorderedList",
                        "insertOrderedList",
                        "indent",
                        "outdent"
                    ]'></textarea></fieldset>
```

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Readonly mode can be triggered only programmatically, when the Editor widget has already been created.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/overview#configuration-Apply

From this point of view, you can use the `kendoWidgetCreated` event, or `kendoRendered`.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/global-events

In the first case (`kendoWidgetCreated`) you will deal with a single Editor instance, while in the second case (`kendoRendered`), iterate all of them by getting all `textarea` elements and the corresponding Editor widget object.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-references

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/events-and-methods#get-widget-reference